# Firefox /FindBar/ addon resurrection

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I found the FindBar addon, that allows the searching on the page with regular expressions. But it works well only in fox 2 and 3. Can someone help me to adapt it for the fox 4 at least. Cause there are some changes in the extensions development since Firefox4.

There are some XPCOM components in that addon, one .dll file and XPCOM functions.

This is the .xpi of the addon:
http://www.oxymoronical.com/files/extensions/FindBarRX/archive/FindBarRX-1.0.1.rev45.xpi

I have read this article about the changes in Firefox4.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0

But i still cannot apply all the changes. I've changed the manifest file according to those instructions but it still doesn't work. Cause i don't know how to register those components properly. For example i don't know what ID they have.

In Firefox2 it allows to set the "Regular Expression" checkbox and input a regex pattern, such as \d to search for a digit. In fox 4 it only shows that checkbox but doesn't react on the find-textbox contents.

There is a file fbTypeAheadFind.js which contains the method Find(), which performs the main functionality of the regex searching. I worked with JavaScript Debugger Firefox addon, XPCOM Viewer. And in fox2 i can see the fbTypeAheadFind.js, loaded in that debugger and i can set a breakpoint in the file to wath the searching process. But in fox4 there is no this file in the debugger.

I guess it's because the XPCOM components aren't loaded properly. So how can i fix it. Maybe it's imposible because there is the .dll file which is responsible for those components loading, but i cannot change it. And maybe i could change all the addon so that it works without those XPCOM stuff, cause i don't really understand it. It's a little hard for me now.

In the link above there is a sentense that says that NSGetModule method should be converted to the NSGetFactory. But the NSGetModule is stored in that .dll file. So i have to rebuild all the source code to create another .dll and obtain the NSGetFactory stuff. But i don't have that source code and don't even know how to create it.

This is my edited **chrome.manifest:**

```
content    findbarrx                          chrome/content/
locale      findbarrx         en-US         chrome/locale/en-US/
skin        findbarrx         classic/1.0    chrome/skin/

overlay     chrome://browser/content/browser.xul              chrome://findbarrx/content/browserOverlay.xul      
overlay     chrome://browser/content/browser.xul              chrome://findbarrx/content/bindingOverlay.xul      
style       chrome://browser/content/browser.xul              chrome://findbarrx/skin/findbarrx.css           

interfaces components/fbITextExtractor.xpt
binary-component platform/WINNT_x86-msvc/components/FindBarRX.dll

component {a5089a1b-2afe-4dae-94b4-c051c3cde90a} components/fbFallbackTextExtractor.js
contract @blueprintit.co.uk/fallbacktextextractor;1 {a5089a1b-2afe-4dae-94b4-c051c3cde90a}
category profile-after-change FindBar-RX-Text-Extractor @blueprintit.co.uk/fallbacktextextractor;1
```

Comment: You cannot use the binaries anymore, because as of Gecko 4 (Firefox 4) binary components need to be recompiled for each and every major version of Gecko (Firefox). Fixing up the Javascript fallback component and forgetting about the binaries seems to be the way to go. Or ask Dave to put the code somewhere public...

Comment: Thanks. But could you point me in the right direction? How can i change that JS code so that it works without .dll?